# How to facet.pivot with spring-data-solr

Tags: spring-data-solr

When declaring this method:

```
@Query(value = "*:*")
@Facet(pivotFields = {"type","status"}, limit = 10000)
FacetPage<SolrCrimeServer> findAllAndFacetOnTypeAndStatus(Pageable page);
```

I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 or more fields required for pivot
>   facets    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)   at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.FacetOptions.addFacetOnPivot(FacetOptions.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery.extractFacetOptions(AbstractSolrQuery.java:246)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery.execute(AbstractSolrQuery.java:120)

With version

**1.1.1.RELEASE**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pivotFields` attribute of `@Facet` takes at least a tuple of field names within one argument.

```
@Facet(pivotFields={"type,status"}, limit=10000)
```

You can have a look at [SolrQueryMethodTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/235abb2486ec58f58a5ca18fec7e3bc359b667a2/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/query/SolrQueryMethodTests.java#L516). Additionally you may vote for this [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-155).

Comment: I couldn't make this work. I ended up using solrTemplate which works great. I will fill an issue asap. Anyway I will vote this as the right answer.

Comment: Could you explain how you set up facet pivot with solrTemplate , thank you

Comment: @lizzie please have a look at [ITestSolrTemplate.java#L451](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/1.4.0.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/solr/core/ITestSolrTemplate.java#L451)