# Pivot faceting with Spring-data-solr using SolrTemplate

Tags: spring-data-solr

How is it possible to add a facet pivot using solrTemplate with spring-solr-data?

This question is related to [How to facet.pivot with spring-data-solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961464/how-to-facet-pivot-with-spring-data-solr) but I am looking for a solution using solrTemplate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at [ITestSolrTemplate.java#L451](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/1.4.0.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/solr/core/ITestSolrTemplate.java#L451).

```java
FacetQuery query = new SimpleFacetQuery(new Criteria("*").expression("*"));
query.setFacetOptions(new FacetOptions().addFacetOnPivot("category", "name"));

FacetPage<SolrBean> page = solrTemplate.queryForFacetPage(query, SolrBean.class);
```

Comment: I have one more problem with facets, I want to set facet.limit to -1. Whenever I use setFacetLimit(-1) it get facet.limit=1 in the query. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in `DefaultQueryParser` using the pageable instead of the _int_ param of `FacetOptions`. Sorry for the inconvenience! would you mind filing a bug report in the projects [jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR)